# resample value with respec to coordinates in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gdal

I have a set of coordinates with some values, and I want to resample to those value with respect to coordinates.Lets say current resolution of coordinates is 0.5 and want to increase resolution up to 0.25 so that the value should also re-sample by same way.

Is there any way to do it  though python?

my datasets looks like:

```
x   y   value
1   3   0.244
1   3.5 0.393
1   4   0.418
1   4.4 0.746
1.5 3   0.086
1.5 3.5 0.797
1.5 4   0.113
1.5 4.4 0.827
2   3   0.867
2   3.5 0.759
2   4   0.629
2   4.4 0.541
2.5 3   0.661
2.5 3.5 0.724
2.5 4   0.106
2.5 4.4 0.424
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, value)
step = 0.25
xx = np.arange(min(x), max(x), step)
yy = np.arange(min(y), max(y), step)
values = f(xx, yy)
```

`f` is a function that takes new values of `xx` and `xy`
and returns corresponding `values`.

Comment: but how to get respective coordinates?

Comment: You can use `x = np.arange(1, 2.5, 0.25)` to get a new x array with 0.25 resolution.